# How to find the matched element using custom ranking algorithm

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need to calculate rank on each account. Rank depends on the account who requested the method.

```
var account; // assumed to be one requesting the method
const allMatches = Account.find({
    $or: [
            { argA: account.argA },
            { argB: account.argB },
            { argC: account.argC }
        ],
        _id: {$ne: account._id}
    });  
const getRank = (item) => {
    let rank = 0;
    if (item.argB === account.argB) {
        rank += 3;
    }
    if (item.argA === account.argA) {
        rank += 2;
    }
    if (item.argC === account.argC) {
        rank += 1;
    }
    return rank;
};
const compare = (a,b) => {
    const rankA = getRank(a);
    const rankB = getRank(b);
    if (rankA === rankB) return 0;
    return rankA > rankB ? 1: -1;
}
// use the compare method 
allMatches.sort(compare);
account.set({match : allMatches[0]['id']});
```

However, I cant use the sort method like this, as it expects an object or a string. 
I need some help to proceed in the correct direction.

For example - 
If there are 3 accounts in the system

```
A1 - {argA: 'A', argB: 'B', argC: 'C'}
A2 - {argA: 'D', argB: 'B', argC: 'F'}
A3 - {argA: 'G', argB: 'H', argC: 'C'}
```

Now if A1 needs to find a match -

```
Rank score with A2 is = 3 // argB is same
Rank score with A3 is = 1 // argC is same
```

Hence A1 will match with A2, and thats what I need.

Comment: What is the desired result and how about some sample input?

Comment: @charlietfl updated description. Let me know  if you need any other clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "sort on the database" using `.aggregate()`

```
let results = await Account.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "$or": [
        { "argA": account.argA },
        { "argB": account.argB },
        { "argC": account.argC }
    ],
    "_id": { "$ne": account._id}
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "rank": {
      "$sum": [
        { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$argA", account.argA] }, 3, 0 ] },
        { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$argB", account.argB] }, 2, 0 ] },
        { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$argC", account.argC] }, 1, 0 ] }
      ]        
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "rank": -1 } }
  /* 
   * Add $skip and $limit for paging if needed
  { "$skip": 0 },
  { "$limit": 25 },
  */
])
```

Also noting that `Account.aggregate()` or `Account.find()` actually returns a `Promise` since the method is async, so you need to `await` that or use `.then()` or provide a callback, depending on your preferred style:

```
Account.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "$or": [
        { "argA": account.argA },
        { "argB": account.argB },
        { "argC": account.argC }
    ],
    "_id": { "$ne": account._id}
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "rank": {
      "$sum": [
        { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$argA", account.argA] }, 3, 0 ] },
        { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$argB", account.argB] }, 2, 0 ] },
        { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$argC", account.argC] }, 1, 0 ] }
      ]        
    }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "rank": -1 } }
  /* 
   * Add $skip and $limit for paging if needed
  { "$skip": 0 },
  { "$limit": 25 },
  */
]).then( result => /* do something */ )
```

That promise/callback resolution is the basic error in your code.

But the general point is you probably want to calculate `"rank"` **on the server** in order to enable paging over larger result sets, and that's a lot smarter than trying to sort *"everything"* in a result array.